Vscodium menu entries flashes white in dark mode
Vscodium menu entries flashes white in dark mode. I am using Verision 1.93 under Linux.
This is maybe related to the underlying electron. But maybe someone has a solution for that.
Thanks in advance.

I was able to solve the problem temporarily by just installing the older Version 1.79 which I had previous. But it shows that there don't seem to be a sufficient quality management in the vscode development which the vscodium is derived from. I doubt that the vscodium guys built this bug in.
